# Is there a way to hint TS which occurrence of generic parameter to use for generic inference?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

Is there a way to hint TS which occurrence of generic parameter to use for generic inference?

```js
type Handler = <T>( // <-- if T is unspecified in method definition and call how can i tell ts to infer it to Ta from Params<Ta> and not Tb of the input?
  func: (params: Params<Ta>) => any,
  input: Tb
) => string;
```

### code sample

```js
type Params<T = Record<string, unknown>> = {
  p: T;
  // other metadata
}

type Handler = <T>( // <-- if T is unspecified how can i tell ts to infer it from Params<T>?
  func: (params: Params<T>) => any,
  input: T
) => string;

type Config = {
  handler: Handler
}

const c: Config = {
  handler: (params, input) => 'ok' // <-- no possibility to pass/state the generic parameter here
}


type AB = {a:number, b:number}
const myHandler = (params: Params<AB>) => params.p.a + params.p.b;

c.handler(myHandler, { a:1, b:2, c:"unexpected" }) // <-- T is inferred to { a:1, b:2, c:"unexpected" }
c.handler<AB>(myHandler, { a:1, b:2, c:"unexpected" }) // <-- this is desired behaviour, can it be done without stating the T = AB explicitly?
```

[ts playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM4B4AqUC8UBKEAxgPYIAm6qwCAlgHYDmANFAK70DW9JA7vQD4BuKAG8AsACgoUMAC4omANxSZAejVQSwABYQEUZBGBxycE1IC%20UqaEhQAEnHrkANvpFYBACigao6AC0gVC0AGaKoajs9KiQROG0EORQOnxQRM6hUMAQrq450cAkofRhHrTAUGEIJMiwiCgYmAIA-KrVHEQK3mCNaArwSGheAJS4ws4gzB0MYGzACphS4zjC1HRMKpK24NAAwiRltIwiEtKpzq7k%20gpOLu4IVjaSpLFV3VCHx6d45zI6K43BA9PrDVCsOYLVbCADkJE4sL8miCIR4shIqFQtAARrRXJUQDkSn0sWpqOZoLpoIwIPR9LQiLJ%20sYPHoEBBnjtuXZoABBABCZzgcnobGQOP0rBxovFkoQ1leR2ohhA92BIl6-VQg216EFAhhzPBADowCa4FAANTGppmk047ZSIgmwH0a76bzINXOYGsURQEUARmlcgATKxugAiDgQAAe8Vy5CjUEs438qMitGiDHKCA5KWKYkDchDUBlEYychj9ITxCTKcVLrdHoQ%20oFPm96qlxeDocr0djdaIDdT6ZRwRyOmzUSgN2xBfLEEBADdaCQ2AhI1lKku50doLxKmkFlAKcATlPoNg8IKoPGwASEsBXCB2pIgA)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the feature requested at [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829), "Noninferential type parameter usage":

> Often with generics, there will be some locations where a type parameter *should* be inferrable from usage, and *other* places where the type parameter should only be used to *enforce* typechecking. This comes up in a variety of contexts.

The proposal there is to come up with some `NoInfer<T>` syntax, which is equivalent to `T` except that the compiler would *not* infer `T` from that location.  This is the flip side  of what you're asking for, but they both would achieve the same goal: a `NoInfer<T>` on the `input` property type is like a "`PleaseInfer<T>`" on the input to the `func()` method.

---

While there is no *official* version of `NoInfer<T>`, there are a few implementations mentioned in the GitHub issue that work for some use cases.  [One I sometimes recommend](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546) is:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
```

This works by taking advantage of the compilers *deferral* of evaluating [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) when the checked type is an unresolved generic.  It cannot "see" that `NoInfer<T>` will evaluate to `T`, until `T` is some specific resolved type, such as after `T` has been inferred.

---

Armed with that, if I change your example code to:

```
type Handler = <T>(
  func: (params: Params<T>) => any,
  input: NoInfer<T>
) => string;
```

Then your examples work as expected:

```
const c: Config = {
  handler: (func, input) => func({ p: input }) // okay,
}
   
type AB = { a: number, b: number }
const myHandler = (params: Params<AB>) => params.p.a + params.p.b;

c.handler(myHandler, { a: 1, b: 2, c: "unexpected" }); // error!
// ------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Object literal may only specify known properties, 
// and 'c' does not exist in type 'AB'
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM4B4AqUC8UBKEAxgPYIAm6qwCAlgHYDmANFAK70DW9JA7vQD4BuKAG8AsACgoUMAC4omANxSAvlKmhIUAHIkAkvQBmEBFmF4A2pgC61qBAAewCPXKooceiCgB+KAAMUAr0EABupjYqkprg0AASXuQANqYi5gAUUjJGHEQKGWCIKKgK8Eho5gCUuMJeIMzZUAxgbMAKeoYmZpgCUjU4wtR0TNGx2gDCJMa0jCIS0lAAFkmpCAqJbmtqGpKk9NRQ+VBTM3N4CzIrW6YFufRErC1tA8L3RBmisgrPwFCqVR2MWBWmgAEEAELzTwhNjIABGplY8NhCLS6j200OyBAmxSaTwhWKaDKxIwkIEr1kZIAdGAaXAoABqakVVB0mnwsZ7GnXfEIDI4vFrVhfOAKACMyIUACZWMcAEQcJyQIgucgK-5VJRQAD0uocCAQZAAhFJ9VAALTWm22u32h3W4QAP1dbvdHvNBoA8vCAFbEP7JWguJDJKDIOA+abJHyoVW0Iw+bh8eiyY2QBDAWgQVCsL2eNxQADkRGLUHIJFzUB4fyctEODCgoJLkOLuyAA)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by changing the types:

```
type Params<T = Record<string, unknown>> = {
  p: T;
  // other metadata
}

type ParamsExtract<T extends (params: Params<any>) => any> = T extends (params: Params<infer U>) => any ? U : never;

type Handler = <Fn extends (params: Params<any>) => any>( // <-- if T is unspecified how can i tell ts to infer it from Params<T>?
  func: Fn,
  input: ParamsExtract<Fn>
) => string;

type Config = {
  handler: Handler
}

const c: Config = {
  handler: (params, input) => 'ok' // <-- no possibility to pass/state the generic parameter here
}


type AB = {a:number, b:number}
const myHandler = (params: Params<AB>) => params.p.a + params.p.b;

c.handler(myHandler, { a:1, b:2, c:"unexpected" }) // error
```

So the generic becomes the function type and the params get extracted from it. See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM4B4AqUC8UBKEAxgPYIAm6qwCAlgHYDmANFAK70DW9JA7vQD4BuKAG8AsACgoUMAC4omANxSZAejVQSwABYQEUZBGBxycE1IC+UqaEixEKVAFEAHjThFgWKBHcR6clQoAAowRzQFeCQ0dDh6EAEASlxheMSRbD9gAKDQ8JjUKIiMBgAzfSgAVWTUqHSoAH5qqAV6CAA3fRVJW3BoAAl48gAbSrx0ADF6X39A4LCS4sK4hNqcNLWQqA0odABafahaMsVj4I5USCIT2ghyKB0+KCJ446gckZGP4OASY-oFQMtGAUDKCBIyAcK0wAkaqjBHCICmmzARDDAbGAyycbg8XimgikKQ2UGodCYPT69gAwiRAbRGCIJNJHsMxggFENAhyrDZJKR6NQXgo6QymXgWTIdOz9ApFoVWBisSThAByEicNU7TQHI48WQkVCoWgAI1oIxBIA+-3CxrU1HM0F00EYAX0tCIsgixkqegQED5vWDdmgAEEAELMuByehsZCm-SsU2x+OJhDWAX04XIEDc0bjfJLaFOdCR9bCApOAB0YGrcCgAGpvYVa9XTVSBdWZTz9CFc-mOaxRPU5ABGZNyABMrGRACIOH5rjlyHOoJYUrt9BCEEA).