# How to ensure the 1st parameter of a function to dictate the generic type?

Tags: typescript

I want to create `Map.get()` with a default value, but I'm having trouble ensuring type safety. My attempt:

```
export function mapGetDefault<K, V>(
  map: Map<K, V>,
  key: K,
  backup: () => V,
): V {
  let val = map.get(key)
  if (val === undefined) {
    val = backup()
    map.set(key, val)
  }
  return val
}

let myMap = new Map<string, Map<number, boolean>>()
let val = mapGetDefault(myMap, 'a', () => new Map()) // val's type: Map<any,any>
```

`myMap` should coerce `V` to be `Map<number,boolean>`, but tooltip says it is `Map<any,any>`. Did I define my function wrong? How can I ensure `backup` doesn't override `map`'s type?

Comment: Please fix your `u.` typo

Comment: You didn't define it "wrong", it's just that `() => new Map()` returns `Map<any, any>`, and the compiler had to pick somewhere from which to infer `V`.  If you always want `V` inferred from `map` and not `backup` then you want [ms/TS#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) and thus this is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67108349/2887218.  If I'm wrong about that, let me know soon.

Comment: See [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5PR2w) for how to apply the other answer to the example in this question